# SQL IN clause causes scan on too many parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble understanding the result of my query here: http://pastebin.com/sGVnq1jU.

It works as intended, however whenever the `T2.CityId IN (...)` clause of the `Clusters` CTE expression reaches more than 6 values to match, the execution plan changes to including
an expensive table scan, and the query gets very slow.

Any ideas on why this might be?

Comment: It will be better if you include your SQL statements in your question. Also, a simple output or/and screenshot of your execution plan.

Comment: The reason is because the query processor thinks that is the optimal plan. The real question, I suppose, is can that behavior be altered?

Comment: Create a CTE using the values in the in-list and then inner-join to it.

Comment: What is `CityId`'s cardinality? How many rows (in absolute values and percents) does those 6 values cover?

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding the IN clause in favor of a join on another CTE table constructed with the parameter values from the IN clause (below)

Additionally, make sure you have an index on the map.ClusterDist.CityId column.

```
DECLARE @cityIds0 int, @cityIds1 int, @cityIds2 int, @cityIds3 int, @cityIds4 int, @cityIds5 int, @cityIds6 int, @cityIds7 int
 SELECT @cityIds0 = 0, @cityIds1 = 1, @cityIds2 = 2, @cityIds3 = 3, @cityIds4 = 4, @cityIds5 = 5, @cityIds6 = 6, @cityIds7 = 7

;WITH Cities AS
(
              SELECT @cityIds0 as [CityId]
    UNION ALL SELECT @cityIds1
    UNION ALL SELECT @cityIds2
    UNION ALL SELECT @cityIds3
    UNION ALL SELECT @cityIds4
    UNION ALL SELECT @cityIds5
    UNION ALL SELECT @cityIds6
    UNION ALL SELECT @cityIds7
), Clusters AS
(
    SELECT T1.*
          ,T2.CityId
      FROM map.Cluster T1
      JOIN map.ClusterDist T2 
        ON T2.Id    = T1.DistId
      JOIN Cities C 
        ON C.CityId = T2.CityId
       AND T2.Zoom  = @zoom
) -- etc...
SELECT * FROM Clusters
```

If that doesn't work for your performance needs, it may be time to switch out some of your CTE tables with good old temp tables that you can index for this particular scenario.